# C# generics + polymorphism workaround?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

So I've currently got a little collection of methods to wrap the Unity WWW class; HandleTexture, HandleText, HandleBytes... but it's a lot of copy-pasted waste. I'm trying to wrap it all up under a generic HandleResult method that hands things off to _HandleResult under the hood. At this point the C# compiler complains about being unable to statically type T to Texture (each of the lines with `closure(...);`

```
private IEnumerator _HandleResult<T> (System.Action<T> closure, System.Action<string> onError){
    yield return webRequest;

    // Can't do a switch statement on Type, needs to be if/else chain :(
    if (SuccessWithoutErrors(onError)) {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(Texture))
            closure(webRequest.texture);
        else if(typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            closure(webRequest.text);
        else if(typeof(T) == typeof(MovieTexture))
            closure(webRequest.movie);
        else if(typeof(T) == typeof(byte[]))
            closure(webRequest.bytes);
        else
            throw new System.NotSupportedException("Could not interpret response data as " + typeof(T).Name + ". Supported types include Texture, MovieTexture, byte[] and string.");
    }
}
```

I've been stuck at this point for a bit now. I'm fairly new to C# so maybe what I'm going for isn't feasible at all. Would greatly appreciate input from people who know more about the type system or what alternatives I should look into to achieve the same effect in terms of code duplication reduction.

Comment: why don't you add overloads for each `T`?

Comment: that way you will have *compile time* checking.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "add overloads for each T" ._.

EDIT nvm nvm I get it, that would work BUT that still means I have a fair amount of duplicate code lying around

Comment: What does the `webRequest` class look like? There's probably a better way to do this, but you'll likely have to make significant changes to that class.

Comment: webRequest is an instance of Unity's WWW class. I'm afraid I can't make any changes to it :( it being icky to work with directly is the reason for the wrapper class I'm writing around it right now

Comment: Instead of `typeof(T) == typeof(Texture)` you may want to do `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Texture))` this helps allow derived classes to also pass through the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# doesn't seem to like it if you cast directly to a generic type. But you can cast to `object` first, then cast to the generic type:

```
private IEnumerator _HandleResult<T> (System.Action<T> closure, System.Action<string> onError){
    yield return webRequest;

    if (SuccessWithoutErrors(onError)) {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(Texture))
            closure((T)(object)webRequest.texture);
        else if(typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            closure((T)(object)webRequest.text);
        else if(typeof(T) == typeof(MovieTexture))
            closure((T)(object)webRequest.movie);
        else if(typeof(T) == typeof(byte[]))
            closure((T)(object)webRequest.bytes);
        else
            throw new System.NotSupportedException("Could not interpret response data as " + typeof(T).Name + ". Supported types include Texture, MovieTexture, byte[] and string.");
    }
}
```

---

A cleaner option might be to supply a function to perform the property selection:

```
private IEnumerator _HandleResult<T> (System.Action<T> closure, Func<WebRequest, T> selector, System.Action<string> onError){
    yield return webRequest;

    if (SuccessWithoutErrors(onError)) { 
        closure(selector(webRequest)); 
    }
}
```

Then you could have a function signature and call site like the following:

```
void DoSomethingWithTexture(Texture t) {}

_HandleResult<Texture>(DoSomethingWithTexture, wr => wr.Texture, onError);
```

This second approach is cleaner and more flexible (what if you later want to add a `Texture2` property to the object you're processing?) but requires an API change and may be more difficult to implement into existing code.

Comment: Isn't the second suggestion simply moving the mess from _HandleResult into whatever supplies the selector func? There still needs to be that check for T's type somewhere, no? (the first part did solve my problem though so I'm marking this as accepted)

Comment: No, there isn't any need to check for the type. The second suggestion moves the type resolution code into the code which knows what type it wants, which is the code that's supplying `closure`. When it's called there it's known what `T` should be so it's trivial to supply the proper selector with all the type checking to be done at compile time. This is complicated if `_HandleResult` is called from another generic method, so it might require passing `selector` through a chain of generic methods. In which case, the first solution might be more appropriate.

Comment: This method is indeed being called from another generic public method to abstract away the coroutine work being done. I do get what you mean though and given the simplicity of the method calling it I may be able to make your suggestion work. At this point the code I have works, so that's all good - but I'll keep trying to clean it up the way you suggested. Either way you've solved it so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private IEnumerator _HandleResult<T>(object closure, System.Action<string> onError)
    {
        yield return webRequest;

        // Can't do a switch statement on Type, needs to be if/else chain :(
        if (true)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Texture))
                ((System.Action<Texture>)closure)(webRequest.texture);
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                ((System.Action<string>)closure)(webRequest.text);
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(MovieTexture))
                ((System.Action<MovieTexture>)closure)(webRequest.movie);
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte[]))
                ((System.Action<byte[]>)closure)(webRequest.bytes);
            else
                throw new System.NotSupportedException("Could not interpret response data as " + typeof(T).Name + ". Supported types include Texture, MovieTexture, byte[] and string.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this. The compiler complains it can't cast Texture (or whichever of the types I'm casting) to generic type T.

Comment: add *where T: class* at the end of the function definition

Comment: Also tried that earlier. Double-checked it, still get `error CS0030: Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.Texture2D' to `T'`

Comment: Nop, the byte array will prevent this as it is an struct

Comment: Then instead of using a generic method you must use an object as parameter

Comment: Yes, and the byte[] thing you mentioned

Comment: error CS0411: The type arguments for method `Response._HandleResult<T>(UnityEngine.Object, System.Action<string>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: That's on your call, you didn't specified the return type

Comment: the method returns an `IEnumerator` regardless of type T. What's bending my brain a little is the fact that the if branch depends on the System.Action<>'s expected parameter type, which isn't obvious to get if you don't know from the onset what type you're looking for. Kinda like a chicken and egg problem.